# Determining visiblity of modeless QDialog?

Tags: qt, qdialog

I'm using Qt 4.4 and my application opens a modeless QDialog that refreshes its contents every 5 seconds using a timer. That is working just fine, but I would like to have the refresh not happen when the dialog is not visible.

I've tried using `isVisible()`/`isHidden()` and `showEvent(QTimerEvent *event)`/`hideEvent(QTimerEvent *event)` but those seem to only indicate when it is first popped up or minimized and reveal no information about when it is behind the main window of the application.

`isActiveWindow()` seems to indicate a slightly related idea, but if possible, I would like to have the window refresh if it's open next to the main window and still visible but not actively being used by the user.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any direct support for this but I think you can probably make this work by checking the coordinates and the [focus widget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qapplication.html#focusWidget). If the current focus widget is on the main form and there is more than some percentage of overlap between the dialog and the main form, as determined based on their [position](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#size-prop) and [size](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#size-prop), then don't refresh.